# How does SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync allow for sequential executions of an async function?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, semaphore

The context for this question is a WPF application. WPF applications use a DispatcherSynchronizationContext.

If I have a button in my application that invokes the Button_Click handler method and I want to ensure all the code in that function is only ever executed by one thread I would wrap it in a semaphore as shown? But what I dont understand is how this works.

Assuming the button was clicked, we would hit WaitAsync() which returns a task that completes when the semaphore is entered, so I guess immediately? Then we would hit await GetLengthAsync() which would bounce us back out to the wpf message loop. Assuming 10 seconds goes by and the button is clicked again, then we would enter the Button_Click method again and hit WaitAsync(), which returns a task that completes when we enter the semaphore, and we cant enter the semaphore so we bounce back out to the message loop? is that how it works?

MAIN QUESTION -
Both times we hit WaitAsync() we are on the same thread, and our semaphore limits the concurrency to only allow one thread to execute that block of code at a time but it wont allow our same thread to enter that code either? the semaphore obviously cant be obtained by say some other threads like thread4 or thread5, but it also cant be obtained even by our same thread again? Any Clarification would be greatly appreciated.

```cs
private SemaphoreSlim semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(1,1);

public async void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();

    try
    {
        // GetLengthAsync takes 40 seconds to complete
        int length = await GetLengthAsync();

        // LongComputeFunc takes 30 seconds to complete
        int aggregate = LongComputeFunc(length);
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphoreSlim.Release();
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't going to end well, re-entrancy bugs are nasty.  Instead of the semaphore you need to set the button's IsEnabled property to false.

Comment: @HansPassant isnt this a common problem or desired capability in asynchronous code? or does it indicate a design error?

Comment: Re-entrancy is never a desired capability.  Either your code is designed for concurrency, or it is not.  Re-entrancy is a sign of a bug.  I second @HansPassant that you will be much better off if you just disable the button before awaiting GetLengthAsync.

Comment: @Nick sure I get that, but whether it’s tied to a button or not isn’t my primary concern. I’m just trying to understand the program flow of execution, are you familiar with how it works?

Comment: The flow is clear.  If you click the button while LongComputeFunc is running, your code will get a thread from the thread pool to block on the semaphore and wait until it is signaled, before continuing the execution of the method.  If you click way too many times, however, you can exhaust the thread pool, i.e. cause all threads from it to wait on the semaphore, and following clicks just queue for the thread pool.  When LongComputeFunc finishes, if the synchronization context runs Release on the main thread, you will be lucky.  Otherwise you may deadlock.

Comment: @Nick No the UI won’t respond to events while the LongComputeFunc is running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Assuming the button was clicked, we would hit WaitAsync() which returns a task that completes when the semaphore is entered, so I guess immediately? Then we would hit await GetLengthAsync() which would bounce us back out to the wpf message loop.

Yes, and yes.

> Assuming 10 seconds goes by and the button is clicked again, then we would enter the Button_Click method again and hit WaitAsync(), which returns a task that completes when we enter the semaphore, and we cant enter the semaphore so we bounce back out to the message loop? is that how it works?

Yes.

> MAIN QUESTION - Both times we hit WaitAsync() we are on the same thread, and our semaphore limits the concurrency to only allow one thread to execute that block of code at a time but it wont allow our same thread to enter that code either? the semaphore obviously cant be obtained by say some other threads like thread4 or thread5, but it also cant be obtained even by our same thread again?

That is correct. Some synchronous coordination primitives do have the capability to allow recursive locks (e.g., `Monitor`), but others do not (e.g., `Mutex`). However, it is unnatural for asynchronous coordination primitives to support recursive locks. (Personally, I'm [against recursive locking in general](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/recursive-re-entrant-locks.html)). Synchronous coordination primitives can get away with recursion because there is the notion of "a thread" that "owns" the lock. For asynchronous coordination primitives, there is no notion of a *thread* owning the lock; rather, a "block of code" owns the lock.

So, that's a long-winded way of saying that `SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync` is not recursive (and shouldn't be).

Now, whether this is a good UX design or not is a different question. As noted in the comments, it's more common for UI to *disable* a button that represents a long-running operation if you only want one to be started at a time. That said, you *could* use the `SemaphoreSlim` approach if you *want* to allow the user to queue up more than one long-running operation. In this case, the `SemaphoreSlim` acts like a sort of implicit queue for your code.