# Synchronizing multiple instances of same application c#

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, semaphore

I have multiple instances of same application, that start at the same time and runs for equal time period (almost). Each application uses Tasks for parallel programming within them. Now I want to limit the number of parallel tasks that can run across these application instances. How can I do it? I tried using semaphore. But no luck. Let's say I am running 5 instance of the application. The first instance creates a semaphore and holds it for n seconds. For n seconds, the remaining four instances are waiting, which is fine. But after that n seconds, the first instance exits, disposing the semaphore instance I guess. After that the remaining 4 starts executing in parallel. Please help.

My code would look something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> itemList = GetItemList();
        Semaphore throttler = new Semaphore(2, 2, "MySemaPhore");

        foreach (var item in itemList)
        {
            throttler.WaitOne();
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    DoWork(item);
                }
                finally
                {
                    throttler.Release();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: We cant see the code

Comment: semaphore should be good to use for your purpose. you might be missing something in your code.

Comment: Sorry.. now added the code @TheGeneral

Comment: I know you are using `Semaphore` and not `SemaphoreSlim` but I wonder if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55460905/585968) applies? (recursive locks).

Answer (score 2):

There is a mistake in your code:
You should use (0, 2) for the Semaphore constructor.
The first argument 0 means that initially there are 0 resources occupied.

This can be seen from the official documentation page. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphore?view=netcore-3.1. Especially the line "_pool = new Semaphore(0, 3);" in the code example. If you want to go deeper into programming, you should start the habit of reading (at least skimming through) the official documentation page of whatever class you are using.

Now this is the corrected code:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
    List<string> itemList = GetItemList();
    Semaphore throttler = new Semaphore(0, 2, "MySemaPhore");

    foreach (var item in itemList)
    {
        throttler.WaitOne();
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                DoWork(item);
            }
            finally
            {
                throttler.Release();
            }
        });
    }
   }
```

Comment: The first point you mentioned is incorrect, I think. The first argument 2 means, two parallel tasks can run. And the second point doesn't work either. Could you please explain how the Waitone inside the Run() will help my case?

Comment: Please don't post code in an image. It can't be used directly like that. You make work for yourself and others. And you make it more likely to get down-voted.